# How can I pipe to a php script in postfix?

Tags: postfix-mta

How can I have all emails going to:

*help[at]mydomain.com* to go to `/home/user/public_html/helpdesk.php`

Do I set that up in `/etc/postfix/virtual` ?

If so what would the syntax be and is anything else needed?

Comment: Do you have a non-virtual domain on that machine? In that case you can just add an entry to /etc/aliases to pipe the e-mail to a php script.

Comment: There are multiple domains on the machine, so I think those would be virtual domains yes?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your main.cf:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps
```

Create /etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps with the following content:

```
/help@mydomain\.com/ helpdesk-php
```

Add the following line to /etc/aliases:

```
helpdesk-php: "|/usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/helpdesk.php"
```

Activate everything with something like the following (depending on your linux distro):

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps
newaliases
service postfix reload
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives this message:
to=<help@mydomain.com>, relay=none, delay=0.21, delays=0.02/0.01/0.19/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for mydomain.com loops back to myself)

Comment: could you post the output of `postconf -n`?

Comment: You will also need to set up virtual_alias_domains: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_domains